# Condition block scoping

Tags: scoping, condition

I have a list of functional rules of the type
`F[x_]:=y;cond[x]` with always the same condition. The list is long and rule 1 of programming says: "Do not copy!"
I surely can somehow "extract" my condition?!

```
fromherecondmusthold statement
F[x_]:=y; (*if cond[x]*)
G[x_]:=z; (*if cond[x]*)
fromherecondmustnolongerhold statement
```

As you see, a slight snag would be that `F[u_]:=v` would not match the pattern, although an underscored variable is a bound one that could have any other name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an example we choose a condition x>0:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2];
With[{y = x_ /; x > 0},
 f1[y] = x;
 f2[y] = 2 x;
 ]
```

Now to test:

```
f1[-1]
(*f1[-1]*)
f1[1]
(*1*)
f2[-1]
(*f2[-1]*)
f2[1]
(*2*)
```

Comment: I desperately tried to include 2 variables. Say, f computes y-x but only if y>x. I tried out about any syntax...except the correct :-/ Can you help again?

Comment: Try:   Clear[f1, cond];
cond[x_, y_] := (x > y);
f1[x_, y_] := x + y /; cond[x, y];

Comment: That works for one function, but not for many. I tried the following: ```With[{assigns}/;cond,f1=...;f2=...;]``` is wrong syntax, With wants a list. Even a nested With doesn't scope where it should: ```With[{v = b_}, With[{u = a_ /; u > v}, g[u, v] := a/b]];```. It also doesn't matter if ```u>v``` is ```a>b``` or any mix - the outer assign doesn't make it into the inner bracket.

Comment: No, the idea was: Clear[f1, cond]; cond[x_, y_] := (x > y); f1[x_, y_] := x + y /; cond[x, y];f2[x_, y_] := x +2 y /; cond[x, y];... repeating cond[...]